# Understanding clone method

Tags: java, clone

I'm reading J. Bloch's effective Java and now I'm at the `clone` method. He mentioned that no constructors were called. But I didn't find it in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()). The second thing is that:

> The provision that
>   “no constructors are called” is too strong. A well-behaved clone
>   method can call constructors to create objects internal to the clone
>   under construction. If the class is final, clone can even return an
>   object created by a constructor.

It seems a little contradictory to me. While he was mentioning that no constructors are called, he said that well-behaved clone can call constructors.

Couldn't you explain what he meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different things:

1. Your own implementation of `clone()` method in your own class which should follow some rules.
2. An implementation of existing `Object.clone()` method.

I believe, when J. Bloch speaks about "no constructors were called", he assumes the behavior of existing `Object.clone()` method. But the quotation you cite is about your own implementation of `clone()` method which in some cases can construct new objects using constructor or even return such object.

Comment: So where is the requirement for not calling the constructors?

Comment: I checked javadocs for JavaSE 5 and 6 and there was no such a quote. Where di he find it?

Answer (score 1):

Classes implementing `Cloneable` interface can call `clone()` method from Object class without having `CloneNotSupportedException`. The signature of the `clone()` in Object class tells why constructors are not called if you call the inherited clone. It is native code, not pure Java.

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

And note that, this is just a shallow copy implementation.